# Return first value after each 60 day period from an Exasol table

Tags: sql, exasol

Below you will find a table with dummy data. Can anyone help me write a query which returns the `touchpoint_id` for the very first touchpoint and then always the first touchpoint after a 60 day period?

With the data below, the query should return `00112023-01-03`, as this was the first touchpoint, and then `00112023-04-20`, since `2023-04-20` is the first touchpoint date after a 60 day period. Then `00112023-06-23`, since this is the first touchpoint after a 60 day period from the previous touchpoint (`2023-04-20`), and so on.

I've been having issues writing a recursive query in Exasol which returns the expected results.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE table1 (
    touchpoint_id VARCHAR(30),
    touchpoint_date DATE
    );

INSERT INTO table1 (touchpoint_id, touchpoint_date) 
VALUES
('00112023-01-03',TO_DATE('2023-01-03','YYYY-MM-DD')),
('00112023-02-05',TO_DATE('2023-02-05','YYYY-MM-DD')),
('00112023-03-02',TO_DATE('2023-03-02','YYYY-MM-DD')),
('00112023-04-20',TO_DATE('2023-04-20','YYYY-MM-DD')),
('00112023-06-23',TO_DATE('2023-06-23','YYYY-MM-DD')),
('00112023-07-05',TO_DATE('2023-07-05','YYYY-MM-DD')),
('00112023-07-26',TO_DATE('2023-07-26','YYYY-MM-DD')),
('00112023-07-26',TO_DATE('2023-07-26','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

I tried to achieve this with the `lead()` and `lag()` window functions, but couldn't identify the first touchpoint as a starting point for the next 60 day period. I tried to do this with the `CONNECT BY` operator, but wasn't sure about the syntax for this use case.

Comment: As far as I know exasol does not support recursive SQL queries. I do not see a way on how to solve this problem without them. You might wanna consider to move this logic into the application level and solve it there.